# Cannot read property 'touched' of null Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this error all the time when create a new input in my page, I don't know why and I loose a lot of time on it without solve. Anyone can help?

1. Follow my HTML:

   ```
   <div class="form-group"
           [ngClass]="{'has-error': (customerForm.get('rating').touched || 
                                     customerForm.get('rating').dirty) && 
                                     !customerForm.get('rating').valid }">
       <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
               for="ratingId">Rating</label>

       <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="form-control" 
                      id="ratingId" 
                      type="number" 
                      formControlName = "rating" />
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(customerForm.get('rating').touched 
                                                || customerForm.get('rating').dirty) && 
                                                customerForm.get('rating').errors">
               <span *ngIf="customerForm.get('rating').errors.range">
                   Please rate your experience from 1 to 5.
               </span>
            </span>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. I already created my 'rating' in FormBuilder:

   ```
   ngOnInit(): void {
   this.customerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
       lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
       phone: '',
       rating: '',
       notification: 'email',
       sendCatalog: true
     });
   }
   ```

I also tried to use the **"safe navigation operator"** in all places where I am calling the ('rating') name in the HTML but, when tried it returns the follow error in the console:
Cannot find control with name: 'rating'

- Remembering that this control is already defined in my FormBuilder and in the HTML (formControlName).

Comment: I re-created this in plunkr, but it seems to work (note - added min/max validator for rating, in order to see the message): https://plnkr.co/edit/1qetXQpikfAaT6ZVWFti?p=preview

Comment: Hi Kevin, I tried to create a new solution with exactly the same code I wrote and it worked properly.

Comment: You forgot <form [formGroup]="customerForm">....</form>

Comment: No Eliseo, It's already in my div structure but a little upward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create a new solution with exactly the same code I wrote and it worked properly. A little bit awkward, I should have a bug in my old project, whatever.